# Java. Создание папок по списку из txt-файла

Tags: java

Я уже всю голову сломал. Писал по-разному, но почему то из всего списка создаётся только два (всегда одни и те же StringBufferInputStream и Writer) каталога, а остальные «создать не удалось». Почему так?

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

    //Читаем файл
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\Dropbox\\dev.java.docs\\2.com.oracle.docs.java.io\\Class\\list.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(strLine); //добавляем в список содержимое текстового файла
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка");
    }

    //Создаём каталог
    for (String name : list) {
        String DIR1 = "D:\\Dropbox\\dev.java.docs\\2.com.oracle.docs.java.io\\Class\\" + name;
        File dir1 = new File(DIR1);

        if (!dir1.exists()) {
            if (dir1.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Каталог " + dir1.getAbsolutePath() + " успешно создан.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Каталог " + dir1.getAbsolutePath() + " создать не удалось.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Каталог " + dir1.getAbsolutePath() + " уже существует.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я проверил код рабочий. Возможно содержимое файла list.txt странное. Выведите содержимое ArrayList<String> list после заполнения и содержимое файла list.txt(если там не километр текста конечно)

Comment: Для таких операций, как создание чего-то на винте в цикле - не забывайте на несколько мс приостанавливать поток через Thread.sleep(100); Также, в некоторых ОС наложены ограничение на название файла/папки - исключите из имён символы \ / : * ? " < > |

Comment: Проверьте работу кода в режиме отладки.